# How to Edit Permission on "Create"? SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

When you go to Lists, and Create. I'd like to show the "Custom Lists" column only to specific group. I don't want the users to be able to create Web Pages, Document Libs .. etc But I'm not able to see how, I tried to create a custom group and edit permission level, but I cant find where exactly.

does enabling "Create" to specific group opens all settings inside that you can't eliminate certain settings from showing to this group?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  There currently is no way out of the box to limit what templates can show to what users without doing custom codeing.